# how to replace a pure-number column by a number-keyword dict ? [python]

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe and a dict below, but how do i replace the column by the dict?

```
data
index     occupation_code
0          10
1          16
2          12
3           7
4           1
5           3
6          10
7           7
8           1
9           3
10          4
……

dict1 = {0: 'other',1: 'academic/educator',2: 'artist',3: 'clerical/admin',4: 'college/grad student',5: 'customer service',6: 'doctor/health care',7: 'executive/managerial',8: 'farmer',9: 'homemaker',10: 'K-12student',11: 'lawyer',12: 'programmer',13: 'retired',14: 'sales/marketing',15: 'scientist',16: 'self-employed',17: 'technician/engineer',18: 'tradesman/craftsman',19: 'unemployed',20: 'writer'}
```

I used a "for"sentence to do the replace, but it's very slow, like that:

```
for i in data.index:
  data.loc[i,'occupation_detailed'] = dict1[data.loc[i,'occupation_code']]
```

Since my data contains 1 million lines and it costs several seconds if i only run it for 1 thousand times.  1 million line may cost a half day!

So Is there any better way to do that?

Great thanks for ur suggestions!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) and if some value missing get `NaN`:

```
print (df)
       occupation_code
index                 
0                   10
1                   16
2                   12
3                    7
4                    1
5                    3
6                   10
7                    7
8                    1
9                    3
10                   4
11                 100 <- add missing value 100
```

---

```
df['occupation_code'] = df['occupation_code'].map(dict1)
print (df)
            occupation_code
index                      
0               K-12student
1             self-employed
2                programmer
3      executive/managerial
4         academic/educator
5            clerical/admin
6               K-12student
7      executive/managerial
8         academic/educator
9            clerical/admin
10     college/grad student
11                      NaN
```

Another solution is use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html), if some values missing get original value, no `NaN`:

```
df['occupation_code'] = df['occupation_code'].replace(dict1)
print (df)
            occupation_code
index                      
0               K-12student
1             self-employed
2                programmer
3      executive/managerial
4         academic/educator
5            clerical/admin
6               K-12student
7      executive/managerial
8         academic/educator
9            clerical/admin
10     college/grad student
11                      100
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming @jezrael's sample data `df`

```
print(df)

       occupation_code
index                 
0                   10
1                   16
2                   12
3                    7
4                    1
5                    3
6                   10
7                    7
8                    1
9                    3
10                   4
11                 100
```

I'd recommend using the `get` method of a dictionary embedded in a `lambda`.  This allows you to embed a default value for things not in the dictionary.  In this case, I return the original value.

```
df.occupation_code.map(lambda x: dict1.get(x, x))

index
0              K-12student
1            self-employed
2               programmer
3     executive/managerial
4        academic/educator
5           clerical/admin
6              K-12student
7     executive/managerial
8        academic/educator
9           clerical/admin
10    college/grad student
11                     100
Name: occupation_code, dtype: object
```